# Linq query to group data

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq

My data looks like this:

```
Person Name, City, Profession
John, London,  Doctor
Bob, Sydney, Doctor
Jill, Hong Kong, Lawyer
Sarah, London, Accountant
```

The city name is in alphabetical order

```
var cities = People.Select(x => x.City).OrderBy(x => x);
```

The data format I would like to get is like this:

```
name: "Doctor", data: [0, 1, 1]
```

This says there are 0 doctors in Hong kong, and 1 in Sydney and London.

The final result should be one line for each profession, with a number for each city.

So with my sample data it would be:

```
name: "Accountant", data: [0, 0, 1] 
name: "Doctor", data: [0, 1, 1] 
name: "Lawyer", data: [1, 0, 0]
```

I've tried the following query:

```
var counts = People.GroupBy(p => p.Profession).Select(group =>
new
{
    Name = group.Key,
    Data = group.GroupBy(g => g.City).Select(c =>
            new
            {
                Count = c.Count()
            }),
});
```

But this doesn't work, as the inner query only knows about it's own cities, so the response doesn't include the 0's, ie it brings back:

```
name: "Accountant", data: [1] 
name: "Doctor", data: [1, 1] 
name: "Lawyer", data: [1]
```

Comment: You're making this too complicated. Just make 2 lists, one with cities, one with professions. Then for each profession, for each city, compose an int list of the counts. It's easy.

Comment: If you want to use Linq, then what you are looking for is `SelectMany` to select into your list in the list.

Comment: Can you please add an answer to show me?

Comment: I need more context, is this data huge and coming from a database? Does it have to be returning in that weird ambiguous city count int list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [completely solve](https://dotnetfiddle.net/n6i8DV) it via `Linq`:

```
var myList = new List<Person>
{
    new Person{ Name = "Jonh", City = "London", Profession = "Doctor" },
    new Person{ Name = "Bob", City = "Sydney", Profession = "Doctor" },
    new Person{ Name = "Jill", City = "Hong Kong", Profession = "Lawyer" },
    new Person{ Name = "Sarah", City = "London", Profession = "Accountant" }
};

var output = (from prof in myList.Select(x => x.Profession).Distinct()
              from city in myList.Select(x => x.City).Distinct()
              join profCity in myList on 
                  new { prof, city } 
                  equals 
                  new { prof = profCity.Profession, city = profCity.City } into subs
              from sub in subs.DefaultIfEmpty()
              group new { sub, city } by prof into res
              select new
              {
                  name = res.Key,
                  data = res.GroupBy(x => x.city).OrderBy(x => x.Key)
                            .Select(x => x.Count(y => y.sub != null)).ToArray()
              }).OrderBy(x => x.name).ToList();
```

**Result:**

```
Accountant: [0, 1, 0]
Doctor: [0, 1, 1]
Lawyer: [1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be the following

```
var professionList = People.Select (pl => pl.Profession).OrderBy(p=>p).Distinct();
    var citylist = People.Select(cl=>cl.City).OrderBy(c=>c).Distinct();
    foreach(var p in professionList)
    {
        Console.Write( String.Format("name:{0}, data:[ ",p));
        foreach(var c in citylist)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0},",
                People.Where (s=> s.Profession == p && s.City==c).Count()
            ));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("]");
    }
```

The results are

```
name:Accountant, data:[ 0,1,0]
name:Doctor, data:[ 0,1,1]
name:Lawyer, data:[ 1,0,0]
```

Comment: Sorting the cities alphabetically they are Hong Kong, London, Sydney this is why the ordering is different.

Answer (score 0):

```
        // get distinct professions
        var professions = peeps.Select(x => x.profession).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
        var citylist = new List<string>() { "Hong Kong", "Sydney", "London" };
        var res = new List<returndata>();
        foreach (var p in professions)
        {
            //init
            var thisres = new returndata()
            {

                ProfessionName = p,
                CityCount = new List<int>()
            };

            foreach (var c in citylist)
            {
                thisres.CityCount.Add(peeps.Where(pp => p == pp.profession && c == pp.city).Count());
            }

        }


    }
}

class returndata
{
    public string ProfessionName { get; set; }
    public List<int> CityCount { get; set; }
}
```

Ugly but this is basically what you want. I don't think returning a random list of int's is good for the number of people in each city, but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

If cities are only 3:

```
           List<Info> infos = new List<Info>()
        {
            new Info() {PersonName = "John", City = "London", Profession = "Doctor"},
            new Info() {PersonName = "Bob", City = "Sydney", Profession = "Doctor"},
            new Info() {PersonName = "Jill", City = "Hong Kong", Profession = "Lawyer"},
            new Info() {PersonName = "Sarah", City = "London", Profession = "Accountant"}
        };

        var newInfos = infos.GroupBy(x => x.Profession, x => x.City).Select(p => new
        {
            Name = p.Key,
            Data = $"[ {p.Count(x => x == "Hong Kong")}, " +
                   $"{p.Count(x => x == "Sydney")}, " + $"{p.Count(x => x == "London")}]"
        });
        // Ordering by name is not necessary
        foreach (var info in newInfos.OrderBy(x => x.Name))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{info.Name}, {info.Data}");
        }
```

Update: If there are many cities:

```
 List<Info> infos = new List<Info>()
        {
            new Info() {PersonName = "John", City = "London", Profession = "Doctor"},
            new Info() {PersonName = "Bob", City = "Sydney", Profession = "Doctor"},
            new Info() {PersonName = "Jill", City = "Hong Kong", Profession = "Lawyer"},
            new Info() {PersonName = "Sarah", City = "London", Profession = "Accountant"}
        };
        var groupOfCities = infos.Select(x => x.City).Distinct();
        var newInfos = infos.GroupBy(x => x.Profession, x => x.City).Select(p => new
        {
            Name = p.Key,
            Data = "[ " + string.Join(", ", groupOfCities.Select(city => p.Count(x => x == city))) + "]"
        });
        foreach (var info in newInfos.OrderBy(x => x.Name))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{info.Name}, {info.Data}");
        }
```

Comment: No, cities could be any number